# How to open a new tab after installing the extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to open a newtab ( that point to a link that show how to use my extension ) after installing the extension. How can I do that ?

Comment: are you sure *every* user will have to see the page? Isn't it better to ask the user to go the page if they wants, or just make a link to the guide on the download page?

Comment: This is a good idea but after a user install the extension then google show the related extensions :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have the background page check for a `hasSeenIntro` key in local storage on page load, which happens each time the browser loads, and when the browser is installed. If it's there, the user has seen the intro interstitial, and if not, show them the page (using [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)) then set the key.

Somewhere in your background.html:

```
if (!window.localStorage.getItem('hasSeenIntro')) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('hasSeenIntro', 'yep');
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: '/help.html'
  });
}
```

You could extend this to show an intro for each new major version/feature in the extension, by not only checking the presence/absence of the key in local storage, but the value as well (e.g., last-seen feature page).

Be careful with this though, it may get annoying to show a page every time the extension updates itself.

Comment: What is the best way to show an help page after installing the extension in your opinion ?

Comment: The way I described, by having a tab open if it has not been shown before.

Comment: Note that there is a new API available in the Dev channel to tell when your extension has just been installed: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/runtime.html#event-onInstalled -- this will only be called the first time the extension is installed, and not each time the browser opens.

Comment: Updated link: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled

Answer (score 6):

You can use the onInstalled listener. It will open options.html only once when the user install the Chrome extension.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL("options.html")},function(){})
})
```